# Code to install a printer driver works on Windows 7 but not Windows 8

Tags: c#, printing, windows-8, drivers

I tried this C# code to add printer and printer drivers to Windows. It worked on Windows 7 but not on Windows 8. Exception (Generic failure) occurred when the code calls `moPrinter.Put()`. Can anyone tell why this error encountered when running Windows 8, and why not Windows 7?

```
    public static bool AddCanonPrinter()
    {
        bool flag = true;
        try
        {
            String portNumber = "9100";
            String printerIP = "157.198.192.42";
            String portName = "IP_" + printerIP;
            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            options.EnablePrivileges = true;
            ManagementScope mscope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath, options);
            mscope.Connect();

            ManagementPath mpPort = new ManagementPath("Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort");
            ManagementClass mcPort = new ManagementClass(mscope, mpPort, new ObjectGetOptions());
            ManagementObject moPort = mcPort.CreateInstance();
            moPort.Properties["Name"].Value = portName;
            moPort.Properties["HostAddress"].Value = printerIP;
            moPort.Properties["PortNumber"].Value = portNumber;
            moPort.Properties["Protocol"].Value = 1;
            moPort.Put();

            ManagementPath mpPrinter = new System.Management.ManagementPath("Win32_Printer");
            ManagementClass mcPrinter = new ManagementClass(mscope, mpPrinter, new ObjectGetOptions());
            ManagementObject moPrinter = mcPrinter.CreateInstance();
            moPrinter.Properties["Name"].Value = "Canon";
            moPrinter.Properties["DeviceID"].Value = "Canon";
            moPrinter.Properties["DriverName"].Value = "Canon iR C2880/C3380";
            moPrinter.Properties["PortName"].Value = portName;
            moPrinter.Properties["Network"].Value = true;
            moPrinter.Properties["Shared"].Value = false;
            moPrinter.Put();
        }
        catch
        {
            int msgCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            string msg = GetSystemMessage(msgCode);
            flag = false;

        }

        return flag;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after I investigate the problem, I have found that the printer drivers names are different in windows 8. so the same code could be used and work successfully in windows 8.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve available printer driver names by code or anywhere in the filesystem?

Comment: Yes. A list of printerdrivers is stored in SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows x64\Drivers\Version-3 in the registry. (replace windows x64 with windows x86 for 32bit drivers)